# Flash not working on a specific site in Safari 7 Mavericks

Tags: safari, google-chrome, adobe-flash

I've tried the following site in Safari:

http://www.2dayfm.com.au/listen/

which seems to activate plugin but stalls while loading:

[image]

This site works fine in Chrome... It may well be a site specific problem but in case I've overlooked some setting I thought I'd ask?

I've tested flash on the adobe website and it seems to be fine, and also I've checked preferences for the site to allow flash but still no luck... Anything I can try?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing Safari's cookies solved the problem for me.

Comment: You should mark your answer as solved.